# Texel Density Checker add-on. Compatible with 3.0?

Tags: uv, add-on, uv-image-editor

Can anyone confirm if:

Texel_Density_3_3_1_291

is compatible with 3.0?

Comment: Where would I find Texel_Density_3_3_1_291?

Comment: https://github.com/mrven/Blender-Texel-Density-Checker/releases/tag/v3.3.1

Comment: But you've confirmed it works, right?

Comment: Yes, the latest version definitely works in 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  It doesn't show up as a UV Editor panel until the 3d Viewport is in Edit mode.